# Is moving a file equivalent to copying and deleting a file?

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, file-transfer

In my Windows PC, I was copying an `.iso` file from my computer to my expansion hard drive and after some time it throws a warning stating the file is in use (it was mounted). As soon as I unmounted and clicked the retry button, the moving ends (as though it had already copied the file and was waiting for deleting the file). Are my assumptions correct?
PS: Comparison with Linux?

Comment: In Windows, Yes.

Comment: If, in Windows, a file is moved from and to the same disk it is not copied. The allocation table of the disk is changed. If moved to another disk it is copied first and then deleted. That's why moving many gigs within the same disk is done instantly